# "export 'store' was not found in '../store'

Tags: vue.js, vuex

HI all I am trying to import my store into my Vuex Route-Gard.

router/auth-guard.js

```
import {store} from '../store'
export default (to, from, next) => {
if (store.getters.user) {
  next()
} else {
next('/login')
}
}
```

store/index.js

```
import {store} from '../store'
export default (to, from, next) => {
if (store.getters.user) {
  next()
 } else {
 next('/login')
 }
}
```

The error I am getting
    export 'store' was not found in '../store'

my vue set up

```
"dependencies": {
"firebase": "^4.3.0",
"vue": "^2.3.3",
"vue-router": "^2.6.0",
"vuex": "^2.3.1"
```

Answer (score 2):

I was able to resolve this, through this method.

`main.js`

```
import {store} from './store'
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  store,
  template: '<App/>',
  components: {
    App
  },
```

`auth-guard.js`

```
import {store} from '../store'
export default (to, from, next) => {
if (store.getters.user) {
  next()
 } else {
 next('/login')
}
}
```

`store/index.js`

```
Vue.use(Vuex)
export const store = new Vuex.Store({
modules: {
products,
bids,
user
}
})
```